# Change Background Color of TextView on Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, colors, textview

I need to change the background color of a TextView.

the font color using ColorStateList what I can change, but the background color does not accept ColorStateList

```
lblEtiqueta.setTextColor (new ColorStateList (
new int [] [] {
new int [] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}
new int [] {android.R.attr.state_focused}
new int [0]
}, new int [] {
Color.rgb (255, 128, 192),
Color.rgb (100, 200, 192),
Color.White,
}
));
```

how to make the background color?

TextView control is created dynamically at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the backgroundDrawable for the TextView.  I've only done my state lists in XML and it would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#00ff00" />
    </item>
    <!-- And so on -->
</selector>
```

From what I understand, from the documentation if you want to do the state list in Java code you will need to use the [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Comment: Arg.  I didn't realize the rest of my answer got chopped up. I've added the changes necessary if you want to do it in java code.