# Changing TextView background color on click

Tags: android, xml, background, textview, selector

I have a `TextView` whose background I would like to change when clicked on. I've tried following the many examples of this I've found on this site and others, but I can't seem to get it working properly.

I'm completely new to android development, so it's quite possible that I'm missing something obvious, so please bear with me. I'm also trying to do this through XML as opposed to Java.

**Main.xml (contained within a table layout)**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/character_option1"
            android:text="Option1" 
            android:textColor="@color/text_off"
            android:background="@drawable/selectors"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />
```

**selectors.xml (in res/drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="@drawable/option_on">
</item>
<item
    android:color="@drawable/option_off" >
</item>
</selector>
```

**colors.xml (in res/values)**

```
<drawable name="option_on">#EBEBEB</drawable>
<drawable name="option_off">#CC0000</drawable>
```

I've also tried `android:color="@color/option_off"` in selectors.xml with `color name="option_off"` in res/values. And I tried simply putting `android:color="#CC0000"` right into selectors.xml. None of it worked.

I'm not sure it's receiving any information from the selector in general. I set the default color to red `#CC0000` just to check, but the background color is still the style's default white.

--

These are the most recent links I have tried as well:

[Selector on background color of TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview)

[Changing Textcolor and Background of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031060/changing-textcolor-and-background-of-a-textview)

[Change Background Color of TextView on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626415/change-background-color-of-textview-on-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying a drawable for a `background`

```
android:background="@drawable/selectors"
```

the item selectors in `selectors.xml` requires you to have the `drawable` attribute set.

You're setting the `color` attribute which won't work.

Instead change `color` to `drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/option_on">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/option_off" >
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here's a [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Refer to the item tag section.

> android:drawable 
>      *Drawable resource*. **Required**. Reference to a drawable resource.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've made the edit, but nothing seems to have changed. Even the "off state" color is incorrect. Would there be any issues with it being contained in a `<TableLayout>`/`<TableRow>`?

Comment: @V_Iker It should work fine in there. Are you sure you rebuilt your project after you made the changes and are not testing on an older version of your app? Works okay for me.

Comment: Ok. So I pushed it to Git and it does indeed work as you said. I use Aide when I'm on the go and even running it through there wasn't working correctly. So it seems I've wasted some hours more than needed. Live and learn, as they say. Thanks again.

Comment: @V_Iker Ah I see, glad you got it working. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

try `@color/yourcolor` to get and `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` to set colors in **colors.xml (in res/values)**

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/android-color-xml-resource-file)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Seems it was my error by not checking it through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

To change View background color on click

in res/drawable/my_onclick_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary">
</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" >
</item>
```

then in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
```

Put in your View's xml

```
android:background="@drawable/my_onclick_background"
```

And you are done.